# $P(X\in B)=1$ when $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ for open and closed $B$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Suppose that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution. If $B$ is a closed Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$,
and $P(X_n \in B) = 1$ for all $n$, then

(a) Prove that $P(X \in B) = 1$.

(b) Show that, however, if $B$ is open subset of $R$, then (a) is false.

For part (b), consider $B = (0,1)$, $X_n := \frac{1}{n+1}, n = 1,2,...$ and $X = 0$. Clearly $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution, $P(X_n \in B) = 1$ for all $n$ but $P(X \in B) = 0$. Thus (a) does not hold. Is this correct?

For part (a) please give me some hints.

Comment: What is your definition of convergence in distribution?

Comment: @dafinguzman $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n \leq x) = P(X \leq x)$ for all $x$ s.t. $F_{X}(x)$ is continuous at $x$ is my definition for convergence in distribution. I think I will have to make use of the the fact that convergence in distribution is equivalent to $E[g(X_n)] \rightarrow E[g(X)]$ in part (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is correct for part **b)**.

For part **a)**, I think what is asked is precisely to show that part of the Portmanteau lemma. We can adapt the proof for the open Borel set case found in the [link provided by d.k.o.](https://maikolsolis.wordpress.com/2012/04/04/distribution-function-weak-convergence-portmanteaus-lemma/) to this case.

Recall that $P(X\in B) = \mathbb E1_B(X)$.

The useful idea is to approximate $1_B(x)$ from above by a decreasing sequence of bounded continuous functions. We can use $$f_m(x)=1 - \min\{1, m d(x,B)\}.$$ 
(Why does it work? Use the fact that $B$ is closed.) We know that $\mathbb Ef_m(X_n)\overset n \longrightarrow \mathbb Ef_m(X)$ for any of these functions $f_m$  by the equivalent definition of convergence in distribution. Since $f_m(X_n)\ge 1_B(X_n)$, we can take expectations and $\limsup$ in $n$ to get 
$$\mathbb E f_m(X)\ge \limsup_n \mathbb E 1_B(X_n)=\limsup_n P(X_n\in B)=1.$$ Now take the limit in $m$ using the bounded convergence theorem to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Portmanteau Lemma](https://maikolsolis.wordpress.com/2012/04/04/distribution-function-weak-convergence-portmanteaus-lemma/), i.e. for any closed $B$

$$1=\limsup_{n\to\infty}P\{X_n\in B\}\le P\{X\in B\}$$

Comment: Is my solution to part (b) correct?

Comment: @minion Yes. Are you allowed to use the Portmanteau lemma? It appears to me that the proof of that part is precisely what was asked. You can still adapt it from d.k.o. 's link, which has the proof for the open Borel subset case.

Comment: @d.k.o. Is there a way to prove it by using the equivalence of convergence in distribution with convergence of expected values of bounded continuous functions and choosing a continuous function as an approximation of the indicator function of the set $B$. Portmanteau lemma was not mentioned in class so I would love to explore a path which does not use it.

Comment: @minion Take a look at the referenced website (it contains proofs ...)